# How to insert form values in two different database table in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

How should I save values of form in two different tables in database using laravel.
I have two tables one is saving only email and password, second is storing other information of user.
How should I do this?

Comment: pleas give me sample code or tutorial related to this

Comment: Can you show us the Models you've created so far as well as the Controller method where you are saving the data?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the form send to a particular Controller method and Store the pertinent data in their relative Models:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   User::create([
       'email' => $request->email,
       'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
   ]);

   Profile::create([
      'website' => $request->website,
      'address' => $request->address,
      // etc...
   ]);

}
```